# VBA code to skip certain values and replace with subsequent qualifying value

Tags: vba, excel

Good day,

I'm very new to coding and completely brand new to coding stuff with vba macros.  After discovering the usefulness of vba in excel, I am now making a effort to learn more about it. Any help or assistance would be very much appreciated.

This is the code I am working with so far:

```
Option Explicit

Const initrow As Integer = 3
Const ENDROW As Long = 65536
Const PrimaryLengthCol As Integer = 1 '"A"

Sub Test()

    Dim lastrow As Double
    Dim i As Double
    Dim irow As Double

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    irow = 0
    i = 0
    For i = 0 To lastrow
        If Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2) = "BLANK" Then
            Continue For
            Cells(initrow + i, PrimaryLengthCol + 3).Value = Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

So essentially the problem I'm encountering is the following:

I have the following in Column "A" (Input column):

- 0
- 14.155
- 14.128
- 15.589
- BLANK
- BLANK
- BLANK
- 15.158

I need the vba code to LOOP through each cell and if the cell is equals to "BLANK" (text string) then the corresponding cell would take the subsequent number.  In addition, if the value from column "A" is equal to zero then output is equal to "void" in column "B".

So the desired output in column "B" (Output Column) would need to be:

- Void
- 14.155
- 14.128
- 15.589
- 15.158
- 15.158
- 15.158
- 15.158

The last criteria is that if the cells in column "A" equal to "BLANK" was preceded by a zero value in the previous cell than those "BLANK" would also equal to a "void" value in the output column "B" :

So if Column "A" had this scenario:

- 0
- BLANK
- BLANK

Output Column "B" needs to be:

- void
- void
- void

I'm unsure of how to apply the Continue For since I want the loop to "skip" over the "BLANK" cells for the next iteration, but still fill the corresponding value into the "B" column with the subsequent qualifying value.  I would prefer to complete this via vba, because once again I am trying to learn the language so I am forcing myself to increase my exposure to it.

Once again any assistance on the matter would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: (a) What code have you come up with so far?  (SO is not a "we code for you" site - it is a "we help get **your** code working" site.)  (b) Does `BLANK` mean the actual text string "BLANK", or a null string, or an empty cell?  (c) This could be easily achieved with Excel formulas, but would require the use of column B and C (unless someone comes up with something fancy).  Does your solution **require** VBA, or are you open to the use of formulae?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on Slai's tips, which I greatly appreciated combined with the code I was already playing with, the problem has been solved with the following code.  I had to split it into 2 functions to accomplish all my original criteria.  If someone has a more efficient way of completing the problem, I'd be more than happy to learn about it.

```
Option Explicit

Const initrow As Integer = 3
Const ENDROW As Long = 65536
Const PrimaryLengthCol As Integer = 1 '"A"

Sub FirstIter()

' initial iteration that exacts value from the adjustment column
    Dim i As Double
    Dim irow As Double

    Worksheets(MatchMLWorksheet).Activate
    irow = 0

    While Not (IsEmpty(Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2)))            ' loop until empty cell
        If Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Offset(, 1) = "Void"    ' cell.Offset(, 1) is the cell on the right
        ElseIf Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Value = "BLANK" Then
            i = irow                           ' sets the count to where cell iteration is
            Do
                i = i + 1                      ' increments the Do Until loop untils
                                               ' it hits the first cell with "BLANK"
            Loop Until Cells(initrow + i, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Value <> "BLANK" Or Cells(initrow + i, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Value <> 0

            Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Offset(, 1) = Cells(initrow + i, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Value
                                               ' Overall counter is at the iteration of "blank"
                                               ' resets counter to match overall loop
        Else
            Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Offset(, 1) = Cells(initrow + irow, PrimaryLengthCol + 2).Value    ' else just use the same value
        End If

        irow = irow + 1                        ' move to the cell below
    Wend

End Sub

Sub FinalIter()
'Checks entire column to see if it contains any "BLANK"

    Worksheets(MatchMLWorksheet).Activate

    Dim num As Double
    num = 0
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iMsg As Integer
    Dim b As Double

    Columns("D:D").Select
        Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="BLANK", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        ' There are no more "BLANK"
        iMsg = MsgBox("There are no more BLANK values!", vbOKOnly)
    Else
        While Not (IsEmpty(Cells(initrow + num, PrimaryLengthCol + 3)))            ' loop until empty cell
            If Cells(initrow + num, PrimaryLengthCol + 3).Value = "BLANK" Then
                b = num                           ' sets the count to where cell iteration is
                Do
                    b = b + 1                      ' increments the Do Until loop untils
                                                   ' it hits the first cell with "BLANK"
                Loop Until Cells(initrow + b, PrimaryLengthCol + 3).Value <> "BLANK"

                Cells(initrow + num, PrimaryLengthCol + 3) = Cells(initrow + b, PrimaryLengthCol + 3).Value
                                               ' Overall counter is at the iteration of "blank"
                                               ' resets counter to match overall loop
            End If

            num = num + 1                        ' move to the cell below
        Wend

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit different approach that might make it easier to use and modify (not tested):

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) ' last cell

While cell.Row > 2                          ' loop until row 3 
    If cell = 0 Then
        cell(, 2) = "Void"                  ' cell(, 2) is the cell on the right of cell
    Else If cell = "BLANK" Then
        cell(, 2) = cell(2)                 ' value from the cell below
    Else 
        cell(, 2) = cell                    ' else just use the same value 
    End If

    Set cell = cell(0)                      ' move to the cell above
Wend
```

---

More advanced approach with Excel R1C1 Formula (also not tested):

```
Dim colB As Range
Set colB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Offset(,1).Resize(,1)

colB.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=0, ""Void"", IF(RC[-1]=""BLANK"", R[1]C[-1], RC[-1]))"

colB.Value2 = colB.Value2  ' optional to convert the formulas to values
```

`.CurrentRegion` gets a rectangular range surrounded by empty cells (similar to clicking on cell `A3` and pressing Ctrl + A), then `.Offset(,1)` is to move the range to column B, and `.Resize(,1)` is optional to resize the range to one column just in case column B is not empty.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance!  I tried out your suggested loop solution but 
Else If cell = "BLANK"
        cell.Offset(, 1) = cell.Offset(-1) 
Doesn't account for the condition where cells equals to "BLANK" (text string) the corresponding cell would take the subsequent qualifying number. So,

15.589
BLANK
BLANK
BLANK
15.158

Needs to come out as:

15.589
15.158
15.158
15.158
15.158

And since the sequence of "BLANK" values are random, I won't be able to offset by a specific offset.

Really thanks for your suggestions! I just learned about .offset by you.

Comment: @NewbieCode ah I see .. I didn't read the question and examples carefully. The loop can be reversed to start from the last cell

Comment: @NewbieCode you can try the updated example and modify if needed.